How to mock when calling a factory class
Using below as a dummy example I can mock the service I'm calling, but I think there should be a better way other than I'm doing it when calling a factory class. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.
Class
public with sharing class RecordCreationController {
    @TestVisible
    private static IRecordCreationService service;

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Map<String, Object> getRecord(Id recordId, String recordType) {
        // Setting up to mock here
        service = service != null ? service : RecordCreationFactory.newInstance(recordType);
        return service.getRecord(recordId);
    }
}

Test Class
@isTest
private class RecordCreationControllerTest {
    @isTest
    static void testGetService() {
        fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
        IRecordCreationService mock = (IRecordCreationService) mocks.mock(
            IRecordCreationService.class
        );
        RecordCreationController.service = mock;
        Map<String, Object> valuesBysProperties = new Map<String, Object>{ 'Property' => 'value' };
        Id recordId = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Account__c.SObjectType);
        String recordType = 'Test';
        // Start stubbing
        mocks.startStubbing();
        mocks.when(mock.getRecord(recordId)).thenReturn(valuesBysProperties);
        mocks.stopStubbing();
        ReviewCreationController.getRecord(applicationId, recordType);
        ((IRecordCreationService) mocks.verify(mock, mocks.times(1).description('service called')))
            .getRecord(recordId);
    }
}


Is there something more specific that you're trying to avoid here (like reducing the lines of code)? Do you want to stick with fflib's ApexMocks? If the answer to that second question is "no, using fflib here isn't that important", then I'd think the alternatives would be to have an inner class (in your test class) that implements IRecordCreationService that you can set instead of RecordCreationController.service = mock; or to have your factory recognize something like 'testRec' that you could then inject some other thing into the factory itself to use when encountering that string.

In other words, I don't suspect you'll be able to shorten the test setup. I think this is one of those situations where the complexity is inherent and mostly irreducible, and all you can really do is shift where that complexity resides (be it in setting up fflib_ApexMocks, making your own test/stub/mock implementation of your interface, or what have you).

Thanks. Apex Mocks is not necessary, but I would like to use it if possible. Can you please elaborate more on the inner test class and how the 'testRec' would work?

Like I said in my comments, I don't think that there's much you can do to reduce the amount of setup that you need to do.
That said...
The simplest way (probably)
The simplest way is to create an inner class, and set the service in your controller
@isTest
private class RecordCreationControllerTest {
    // This could be part of the inner class, but making it static here
    //   makes it slightly easier to access
    static Integer timesCalled = 0;

    // A test class is still just a class
    // You can make an inner class
    private class TestImpl implements IRecordCreationService {
        public Map<String, Object> getRecord(String recordId) {
            timesCalled++;

            return (Map<String, Object>)JSON.serialize(new Account(Id = recordId, ));
        }
    }

    @isTest
    static void testGetService() {
        // While you're writing fewer lines here, you're still writing lines
        //   to make the inner class and setting things up in the SUT
        //   (system under test) itself
        RecordCreationController.service = new TestImpl();
        Id testId = '001000000000001';

        // Call the SUT, the "Act" part of "Arrange, Act, Assert"
        Test.startTest();
        Map<String, Object> result = RecordCreationController.getRecord(testId, 'Account');
        Test.stopTest();

        Assert.areEqual(testId, (Id)result.get('id'), 'Id was wrong');
        Assert.areEqual(1, timesCalled, 'did not call the factory the appropriate number of times');
    }
}

Another way (additional level of indirection)
Assuming that your factory looks something like this
// If you use a Map instead of a Switch, it's pretty similar
// The main difference is when all of these individual classes are instantiated
//   (with the Switch approach being slightly better (for performance) for large 
//   numbers of services, since you'd only be instantiating one when required)
public class RecordCreationFactory {
    public static IRecordCreationService newInstance(String recType) {
        IRecordCreationService result;

        switch on recType {
            when 'type1' { 
                result = new Type1();
            }
            when 'type2' {
                result = new Type2();
            }
            when else {
                result = null;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

Then you can make a simple modification to allow you to inject something from within your test
public class RecordCreationFactory {
    // public, or private with the @testVisible annotation to allow you to
    //   set it from a test (but not from elsewhere in code)
    public static IRecordCreationService testImplementation;

    public static IRecordCreationService newInstance(String recType) {
        IRecordCreationService result;

        // one option, detect and return immediately
        // if(testImplementation != null) {
        //     return testImplementation;
        // }
        // return result;

        switch on recType {
            when 'type1' { 
                result = new Type1();
            }
            when 'type2' {
                result = new Type2();
            }
            when else {
                // another option, more "in the same flow" as normal code
                // would still result in null in non-test contexts
                result = testImplementation;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

Then, in your test class...
@isTest
private class RecordCreationControllerTest {
    // This could be part of the inner class, but making it static here
    //   makes it slightly easier to access
    static Integer timesCalled = 0;

    // A test class is still just a class
    // You can make an inner class
    private class TestImpl implements IRecordCreationService {
        public Map<String, Object> getRecord(String recordId) {
            timesCalled++;

            return (Map<String, Object>)JSON.serialize(new Account(Id = recordId, ));
        }
    }

    @isTest
    static void testGetService() {
        // While you're writing fewer lines here, you're still writing lines
        //   to make the inner class and setting things up in the SUT
        //   (system under test) itself
        RecordCreationFactory.result = new TestImpl();
        Id testId = '001000000000001';

        // Call the SUT, the "Act" part of "Arrange, Act, Assert"
        Test.startTest();
        Map<String, Object> result = RecordCreationController.getRecord(testId, 'Account');
        Test.stopTest();

        Assert.areEqual(testId, (Id)result.get('id'), 'Id was wrong');
        Assert.areEqual(1, timesCalled, 'did not call the factory the appropriate number of times');
    }
}

Both approaches should achieve the same result. If I had to choose, I'd pick the "simple" way. You're trying to remove/mock direct dependencies. The first approach works more directly (service is set, so RecordCreationFactory isn't called) than the second (which calls RecordCreationFactory, to get the exact same inner class as the first approach).
The fewer layers that you need to work with in a test, the easier (better?).
The first approach goes 2 layers deep (SUT -> dependency, which we've injected).
The second approach goes 3 layers deep (SUT -> dependency -> special setup we've done to inject an inner class)

I would just follow the standard fflib pattern here for service classes
Production Code
public with sharing class RecordCreationController {

@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String, Object> getRecord(Id recordId, String recordType) {
    
    return RecordCreationService.getRecord(recordId,recordType);
}

}
public class RecordCreationService {
  public static Sobject getRecord(Id recordId, String recordType) {  // service entry point
    return service().getRecord(recordId,recordType);

    private static IRecordCteationService service() { // calls factory
      return (IRecordCreationService) Application.Service.newInstance(IRecordCreationService.class);
    } 
}
/**
*  Concrete (production) implementation of service class methods
**/
public class RecordCreationServiceImpl implements IRecordCreationService {
  public SObject getRecord(Id recordId, String recordType) {

    ... code here ...
    return sobject;
}

public interface IRecordCreationService {  // interface used by prod and mock classes
  SObject getRecord(Id recordId, String recordType);
}

/**
*  Standard fflib class for factories that support mocks and prod
*/
public class Application {
  public static final fflib_Application.ServiceFactory Service = 
    new fflib_Application.ServiceFactory( 
        new Map<Type, Type> {
                IRecordCreationService.class => RecordCreationServiceImpl.class,
   ...  // other service classes
        });
 }

Test Method exploiting ApexMocks
@IsTest private void myTestMethod() {
  // Given mocking environment
  fflib_ApexMocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();

  // Given mock Service results
  Map<String, Object> valuesByProperties = new Map<String, Object>{ 'Property' => 'value' };
  // Given mockRecordId  
  Id recordId = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Account__c.SObjectType);
  
  mocks.startStubbing();
  mocks.when(mock.getRecord(recordId)).thenReturn(valuesBysProperties);
  mocks.stopStubbing();


  // Given mock Service 
  RecordCreationServiceImpl mockRecordCreationService = (RecordCreationServiceImpl) mocks.mock(RecordCreationServiceImpl.class);
  mocks.startStubbing();
  mocks.when(mock.getRecord(recordId,'Test'))
       .thenReturn(valuesByProperties);
  mocks.stopStubbing();
  // Given mock Service injected
  Application.Service.setMock(RecordCreationService.class,
                              mockRecordCreationService);

  // When code under test invoked
  ReviewCreationController.getRecord(applicationId, recordType);
  // Then verify service called
  ((IRecordCreationService) mocks.verify(mock, mocks.times(1).description('service called')))
        .getRecord(recordId,'Test');

Notes:
1 - I changed your service class to support recordType as a parameter. If for whatever reason, recordType can't be added to your getRecord() method, then create another service that accepts a recordType that getRecord() can use at runtime
2 - The standard fflib pattern of selector-domain-service-unit-of-work (IMHO) should be adopted wholeheartedly and not in piecemeal in order to get the most out of ApexMocks. It allows test methods to mock domain, services, selector, and units of work and thus avoid doing costly DML for most test method use cases. Caveat - I'm an fflib fanboy as I've used it to great effect over 10 years.
3 - There's an excellent example of using ApexMocks without fflib pattern for PROD code in this Joe Lemmer blog. If this is just your first toe in the water with ApexMocks and your code is not structured as domain-service-selector-unit-of-work, then this blog is for you.

Thanks. I'm familiar with fflib, but I wasn't sure if you needed to strictly use the service layer for SObjects.
